# 3rd party Angular 4 control in hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an AngularJS 1.5 app to Angular 4. I have successfully managed to bootstrap the application and have an Angular4 component loaded in an AngularJS component template.

Now I am trying to use a 3rd party Angular4 tree component but it is unable to load it. I know that only components/services defined in the root module are available after downgrading but is there a way use 3rd party Angular4 component in a hybrid app?

If not then that means until the complete application is converted to Angular 4 no third party Angular 4 components and services can be used in the hybrid app? Is this assumption correct /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now. I forgot to import the 3rd party module in my @NgModule imports. Once I added that it started working. So Angular4 third party components can be used in a hybrid app.